# Bone controlling eye texture movement not moving straight

Tags: texturing, bones

I have no idea how to phrase the question, sorry for that.

I'm completely new to blender, I've followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kB9cJ3wOoPk) to a T to create a bone that controls the movement of a texture (in this case the eyes, as I have a cartoony anime style head and spheres don't work with their shape) and it works exactly as it does in the tutorial, but I'm having a problem with the eyes not moving "straight" together horizontally - they move almost along a curve. Vertically they seem to move fine.

[image: https://gyazo.com/09e13f44ce43dae0dba09159b48c2263]

[image: https://gyazo.com/23195c472ee7efd600e513d24b3c1987]

This appears in the tutorial as well however it isn't addressed. Is there a way I can make the eyes follow the bone exact rather than how it follows above? (and yes the eyes move in the opposite direction of the bone.. I tried to fix this as the person in the video did but for some reason it doesn't work.)

Comment: have you tried rotating the eyes geometry or their uv maps ?

Comment: Could you upload your blend file file here blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com so I can try to help you?

Comment: @GeraldDegeneve yes i have, it just ends up moving the eyes all over the place instead of where they should be.

Comment: @Tak here's the file, beware it's a real mess since it was more for learning to use the program than anything else lol

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=4957" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4957/)